# inserting data after certain data (double linklist)

Tags: java, linked-list

Hey, so I wanted to insert one data after the input data (not index).
I've tried but it always at the end, the data that i want to insert end up at the dront of the link list..

> **public static void insertAfter(Object o,Object c){

```
    Node newN = new Node();
    Node help = new Node();
    Node help2 = new Node();
    newN.data = o;
    help = head.next;
    if(isEmpty()){
        head = newN;
        newN.next=head;
        newN.prev=head;
    }
    else{
        do{
            help=help.next;
            System.out.println(help);
        }while(help.next!=head || !help.data.equals(c));
        help2 = help.next;
        newN.next = help2;
        help2.prev = newN;
        help.next=newN;
        newN.prev=help;
    }**
```

anyone could help?
thx a bunch!

Comment: Your variable naming scheme is very poor. What is help and help2 for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try another ending condition:

```
while(help.next!=head && !help.data.equals(c));
```

By the way, I can only advise you to avoid do...while without serious reasons, and to use getters and setters.

Your code should also be structured diffently. Why are you not writing a private method which just make the insert, i.e. your 5 last lines? Everything would be more readable and reusable.

Also, your variables need clear and meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

What are the objects that you are comparing? if they are something other than string than you will have to override equals() method in order to get the correct comparison.

Answer (score 0):

### Do it yourself

I begun fixing your solution but ended writing a whole new implementation when wanting to test it... so here goes:

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<T> {

    private class Node {
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;
        private T data;

        Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public void insertAfter(T afterThis, T objectToAdd) {

        // cannot insert after in a empty list?!
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("list is empty?");

        // find the node where we want to insert the element
        Node after = findNodeByObject(afterThis);

        // create the node and update the links
        addAfter(after, new Node(objectToAdd));
    }

    private void add(T objectToAdd) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = new Node(objectToAdd);
            head.next = head;
            head.prev = head;
        }
        else {
            addAfter(head.prev, new Node(objectToAdd));
        }
    }

    private void addAfter(Node after, Node toAdd) {

        Node afterAfter = after.next;

        after.next = toAdd;
        afterAfter.prev = toAdd;

        toAdd.prev = after;
        toAdd.next = afterAfter;
    }

    private Node findNodeByObject(T object) {

        Node current = head;

        while (true) {
            if (current.data.equals(object))
                return current;

            if (current.next == head)
                break;

            current = current.next;
        }

        throw new NoSuchElementException("" + object);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        List<T> printList = new LinkedList<T>();

        Node current = head;

        while (true) {
            printList.add(current.data);

            if (current.next == head)
                break;

            current = current.next;
        }

        return printList.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DoubleLinkedList<String> list = new DoubleLinkedList<String>();

        list.add("first");
        list.add("third");
        list.insertAfter("first", "second");

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

### Extend LinkedList

... and add the insertAfter method like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

    private void insertAfter(T first, T second) {

        ListIterator<T> iterator = listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().equals(first)) {
                iterator.add(second);
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Could not find " + first);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyList<String> list = new MyList<String>();
        list.add("first");
        list.add("third");
        list.insertAfter("first", "second");

        System.out.println(list); // prints "[first, second, third]"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he's trying to create linked list without help of any library data structures.

Comment: Then why program in in java.. ;)

Comment: To learn data structures? Java syntax is somewhat "easier" to learn than other oop languages', imo

Comment: Added a own implementation of double linked list. Hopefully he can use it... :)